# Joining a list of data.frames with intersected genes and redundant columns into a single unique data.frame

Tags: r, reduce, purrr

I have a `list` of `data.frame`s. Some of the `data.frame`s are redundant and among the non-redundant ones the rows (indicated by an `id` column) are not identical but do overlap:

```
set.seed(2)
ids.1.2 <- paste0("id",sample(30,10,replace = F))
ids.3.4 <- paste0("id",sample(30,20,replace = F))

df.1 <- data.frame(id = ids.1.2,matrix(rnorm(100),10,10,dimnames = list(NULL,paste0("s.1.2:",1:10))))
df.2 <- df.1
df.3 <- data.frame(id = ids.3.4,matrix(rnorm(300),20,15,dimnames = list(NULL,paste0("s.3.4:",1:15))))
df.4 <- df.3

df.list <- list(df.1, df.2, df.3, df.4)
```

So in this case, `df.1` and `df.2` are identical, and so are `df.3` and `df.4`, and both sets intersect on `id`s:

```
"id6"  "id21" "id17" "id5"  "id24" "id11" "id12
```

Is there a `purrr::reduce` or similar way to combine this list into a single `data.frame` with unique columns and the intersecting `id`'s?

I'd use:

```
purrr::reduce(df.list, dplyr::inner_join,by = "id")
```

If all `data.frame`s had unique columns. But in my case using this adds the `.x`, `.y`, ... suffices to the redundant columns.

Comment: Maybe remove `by = "id"` and rely on the default behavior which is to use all variables with common names.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's what you what, but I'd remove identical dataframes at first and then combine the rest. It's not a pretty solution and you may adjust it here and there, but if I got it right, it gives you your desired result. You might want to include a line that removes identical combinations in the `combinations` dataframe, so that you can be sure that there are no errors when removing the identical dfs from your list.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# create all possible combinations
names(df.list) <- 1:length(df.list)
combinations <- crossing(names(df.list), names(df.list))
colnames(combinations) <- c("v1", "v2")

# remove self-combinations
combinations <- combinations[!combinations$v1 == combinations$v2,]

# check which cases are identical
combinations$check <- sapply(1:nrow(combinations), function(x){combinations[x,] <- identical(df.list[[combinations$v1[x]]], df.list[[combinations$v2[x]]])})
combinations <- combinations[combinations$check == T,]

# remove identical cases
for(i in 1:length(df.list)){
  if(combinations$v1[i] == names(df.list)[i] & combinations$v1[i] %in% names(df.list)){df.list[i] <- NULL}

}

# combine dataframes
bind_rows(df.list)
```